# Magento create search field for tracking numbers

Tags: magento

I'm breaking my head to create a search field to display track my order feature in magento.
Let me explain you clearly, If you go to `www.aramex.com` on the right side bar there's a box named `Track Your Shipment` with a track button.

I want to add a similar kind of functionality in my magento site but not as sidebar. I planned to add a link named `Track my Order` in footer. If user clicks that it should open a popup with search field like `aramex.com`. There users can able to track their orders by giving their tracking number/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extension for doing this, this is the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/guest-order-status.html